# I'm trying to log creation of threads, but my code isn't working, and there is no error message

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm testing this by running the code and then creating a thread. The expected outcome is for the bot to send an embed in the logs channel that informs me of the creation of the thread, but the bot isn't sending anything and there is no error message in the console. Other parts of my code that log things like channel creation, message edits, etc, are working fine.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.messages = True
my_secret = os.environ['TOKEN']
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='~', intents=intents)

logs_chan_id = 1004891934709518376
color_green = 0x00ff1a

@client.event
async def on_thread_create(thread):
  embed = discord.Embed(title="Thread Created", description=thread.name, colour=color_green)
  logs = client.get_channel(logs_chan_id)
  await logs.send(embed=embed)

client.run(my_secret)
```

for context:

[discord.on_thread_create(thread)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_thread_create)

[class discord.Thread](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Thread)

Comment: Could you run `print(discord.__version__)` and ensure you're on version `2.0.0a`? if you're not, update using `pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py`

Comment: @Jawad The version I'm on is 1.7.3. I tried updating it but it's giving me a syntax error. (I'm using python on repl.it if that's relevant)

Comment: Shouldn't be. Why is it giving you the error, what does it say, and where?